# How Jenkinsfile implements the default value obtained from the file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This method cannot be achieved, is there a way to achieve my needs.

```
def VERSION = readFile(file: '/opt/version').trim()

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'maven'
  }
  
  parameters {
    string(name: 'version', defaultValue: VERSION, description: 'version')
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) Plugin, it allows you to generate the choices based on a file or by running your own custom groovy script.

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` is a Declarative Pipeline Step
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

This means it can only be used in a `steps` block.
e.g.

```
stage("Stage1"){
  steps{
    script{
      fileContents = readFile('/opt/version').trim()
    }
  }
}
```

To make dynamic parameters you would need to use the https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ plugin.
But it would also depend on where the file you are trying to open is located as to whether this is possible or not.